# Eval() function alternative

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a json file where i am rendering  the template and have an object like

```
"templateLabelEval":"return $row->['document_code'];"
```

I am rendering the label by using

```
eval(templateLabelEval);
```

Is there any other alternative way where i could avoid using eval as it is considered to be a bad practice

Comment: Try jsonp? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: @JoeFrambach: That's only needed for cross-domain issues. Might as well just use `eval`, since it's doing pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Do you really have to use eval? Does the value of `templateLabelEval` really have be arbitrary code? Can't it just be the actual string value you want to show?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the code string has a `return` statement, `eval` alone wouldn't work anyway, but you could use `Function()`.

```
var result = Function(data.templateLabelEval)();
```

This has nearly all the same security concerns, but not so much the performance issues that eval has (or had). So of course, you should only execute code that is secure.

To explain the code, passing the string to the `Function` constructor creates a new function object with that strings as its body. (I assume the function needs no parameters defined for now.) So the trailing `()` invokes the function immediately and the result is stored in `result`.

You could store the function itself if you want, and then invoke it later as many times as you'd like.